# Python can't take input while using functions

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kaggle

I am working on the Housing Prices problem hosted on Kaggle.  While building my model, I figured that it makes sense to reuse some of the code that I've been using for the train dataset, on the test set as well so I took the code performing mutual operations into one function definition. In this function, I am handling missing values and using its return to perform one-hot-encoding and using it on Random Forest Regression. However, its throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Boston-Kaggle/Model.py", line 56, in <module>
    sel.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\from_model.py", line 196, in fit
    self.estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 249, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 542, in check_array
    allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 56, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

I did not have this problem while using the same code without organizing it into a function.  `def feature_selection_and_engineering(df)` is the function in question. The following is my entire code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

def feature_selection_and_engineering(df):
    # Creating a series of how many NaN's are in each column
    nan_counts = df.isna().sum()

    # Creating a template list
    nan_columns = []

    # Iterating over the series and if the value is more than 0 (i.e there are some NaN's present)
    for i in range(0, len(nan_counts)):
        if nan_counts[i] > 0:
            nan_columns.append(df.columns[i])

    # Iterating through all the columns which are known to have NaN's
    for i in nan_columns:
        if df[nan_columns][i].dtypes == 'float64':
            df[i] = df[i].fillna(df[i].mean())
        elif df[nan_columns][i].dtypes == 'object':
            df[i] = df[i].fillna('XX')

    # Creating a template list
    categorical_columns = []

    # Iterating across all the columns,
    # checking if they're of the object datatype and if they are, appending them to the categorical list
    for i in range(0, len(df.dtypes)):
        if df.dtypes[i] == 'object':
            categorical_columns.append(df.columns[i])

    return categorical_columns

# take one-hot encoding
OHE_sdf = pd.get_dummies(feature_selection_and_engineering(train))

# drop the old categorical column from original df
train.drop(columns = feature_selection_and_engineering(train), axis = 1, inplace = True)

# attach one-hot encoded columns to original data frame
train = pd.concat([train, OHE_sdf], axis = 1, ignore_index = False)

# Dividing the training dataset into train/test sets with the test size being 20% of the overall dataset.
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, train['SalePrice'], test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

randomForestRegressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)

# Invoking the Random Forest Classifier with a 1.25x the mean threshold to select correlating features
sel = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100), threshold = '1.25*mean')
sel.fit(x_train, y_train)

selected = sel.get_support()

# linearRegression.fit(x_train, y_train)
randomForestRegressor.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Assigning the accuracy of the model to the variable "accuracy"
accuracy = randomForestRegressor.score(x_train, y_train)

# Predicting for the data in the test set
predictions = randomForestRegressor.predict(feature_selection_and_engineering(test))

# Writing the predictions to a new CSV file
submission = pd.DataFrame({'Id': test['PassengerId'], 'SalePrice': predictions})
filename = 'Boston-Submission.csv'
submission.to_csv(filename, index=False)

print(accuracy*100, "%")
```

**new error**:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/Documents/Boston-Kaggle/Model.py", line 76, in <module>
    x_train, encoder = feature_selection_and_engineering(x_train)
  File "/home/onur/Documents/Boston-Kaggle/Model.py", line 57, in feature_selection_and_engineering
    encoder = train_one_hot_encoder(df, categorical_columns)
  File "/home/onur/Documents/Boston-Kaggle/Model.py", line 30, in train_one_hot_encoder
    return enc.fit(categorical_df)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 493, in fit
    self._fit(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 80, in _fit
    X_list, n_samples, n_features = self._check_X(X)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 67, in _check_X
    force_all_finite=needs_validation)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 542, in check_array
    allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 60, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError("Input contains NaN")
ValueError: Input contains NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing code is a good idea, but beware how the scope of variables change when you put code into a function.

The error you are getting is caused because there are `NaN` values in the array you input into the random forest. In your `feature_engineering_and_selection()` function, you are removing the `NaN` values, but `df` is never returned from the function, so the original, unmodified `df` is used in the model.

I suggest splitting up your `feature_engineering_and_selection()` function into different components. Here I made a function that just removes `NaN`s.

```
# Iterates through the columns and fixes any NaNs
def remove_nan(df):
    replace_dict = {}

    for col in df.columns:

        # If there are any NaN values in this column
        if pd.isna(df[col]).any():

            # Replace NaN in object columns with 'N/A'
            if df[col].dtypes == 'object':
                replace_dict[col] = 'N/A'

            # Replace NaN in float columns with 0
            elif df[col].dtypes == 'float64':
                replace_dict[col] = 0

    df = df.fillna(replace_dict)

    return df
```

I suggest filling `NaN` numerical values with 0 instead of the mean. For this data, there are 3 numerical columns with nan values: `LotFrontage` (feet of street connected to property), `MasVnrArea` (masonry veener area), `GarageYrBlt` (garage year built). If there is no garage, then there is no garage year built, so it makes sense to have the year as 0 instead of the average year, etc.

There is also some work that needs to be done with the one hot encoder you have set up. Creating a one-hot-encoding can be tricky, because the training data and the test data need to have the same columns. If you have the following training and test data

Train

```
| House Type |
| ---------- |
| Mansion    |
| Ranch      |
```

Test

```
| House Type |
| ---------- |
| Mansion    |
| Duplex     |
```

Then if using `pd.get_dummies()` the train columns will be `[house_type_mansion, house_type_ranch]` and the test columns will be `[house_type_mansion, house_type_duplex]`, which won't work. However, using sklearn, you can fit a one hot encoder to your train data. When transforming the test dataset, it will create the same columns as the train data set. The `handle_unknown` parameter will tell the encoder what to do with `duplex` in the test set, either `ignore` or `error`.

```
# Fits an sklearn one hot encoder
def train_one_hot_encoder(df, categorical_columns):
    # take one-hot encoding of categorical columns
    categorical_df = df[categorical_columns]
    enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')
    return enc.fit(categorical_df)
```

To combine the categorical and non categorical data, again I suggest making a separate function

```
# One hot encodes the given dataframe
def one_hot_encode(df, categorical_columns, encoder):
    # Get dataframe with only categorical columns
    categorical_df = df[categorical_columns]
    # Get one hot encoding
    ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(encoder.transform(categorical_df), columns=encoder.get_feature_names())
    # Get float columns
    float_df = df.drop(categorical_columns, axis=1)
    # Return the combined array
    return pd.concat([float_df, ohe_df], axis=1)
```

Finally, your `feature_engineering_and_selection()` function can call all of those functions.

```
def feature_selection_and_engineering(df, encoder=None):
    df = remove_nan(df)
    categorical_columns = get_categorical_columns(df)
    # If there is no encoder, train one
    if encoder == None:
        encoder = train_one_hot_encoder(df, categorical_columns)
    # Encode Data
    df = one_hot_encode(df, categorical_columns, encoder)
    # Return the encoded data AND encoder
    return df, encoder
```

There were a few things I had to fix to make the code run, I have included the entire modified script in a gist here https://gist.github.com/kylelrichards11/6be90d92a7dd6a5cc9a5290dae3ff94e

Comment: It looks like the error is caused by the `handle_unknown` argument not being properly set in this line: `enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')`. Is that line the same in your code because I am not getting that error when running the code in the gist.

Comment: My `handle_unknown='unknown'` lol so I fixed it.  But now I'm getting a ValueError, which says that there is a NaN in the input.

Comment: and when I use your code completely as it is, I get this: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

Comment: maybe because I have a newer version of Pandas.

Comment: I was getting that warning too, I updated the definition of `remove_nan()` to fix. As far as your `ValueError` I'm guessing that your `remove_nan` function is not working correctly, or you are not calling `reset_index()` as I did in the gist after calling `train_test_split()`

Comment: I've copy/pasta your code as it is.  Its still giving me the warning and I'm not finding the boston_submission.csv file.

Comment: What versions of python, pandas, and sklearn are you using? I have `python 3.7.4`, `pandas 0.25.0`, and `scikit-learn 0.21.3`.

Comment: Nvm.  I fixed that error but now I'm getting a score of 0.15 on Kaggle.  I feel like I've overfitted the model because my accuracy score is 98%.

Comment: Yes you are probably overfitting. Try other models or more feature engineering such as PCA. Also because we are doing regression, we cannot use accuracy since our predicted values will never be exactly the same as the true values. Try using MSE or another metric. If you would like help with machine learning techniques feel free to send me your contact info and I will be happy to help!